# Can a PVRTC 4 texture be displayed on the windows Editor?

Tags: windows, editor, pvrtc

I would like to know if a PVRTC 4 texture intended for an Android device, could be displayed on the Unity Editor when doing tests. Now is showing me a pink solid colour, I guess it's because windows is not able to handle this texture compression. Thanks.